# Как редактировать сообщение с помощью его id? Discord JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Почему у меня не редактирует сообщение?

```js
    let server = bot.guilds.get('ид сервера');
    let stats = server.channels.get('Ид канала');
    let stats_msg = stats.message.get('Ид сообщения');
    stats_msg.edit(`Текст`);
```

При запуске бота появляется ошибка.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильно написано свойство `messages`, а не `message` ([docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=messages)). Но даже если вы напишете правильно, то коллекция будет пуста, т.к. это фактически кэш тех сообщений, которые вы запрашивали раньше. Нужно использовать `fetchMessage(id)` - одно сообщение по id, `fetchMessages()` - все сообщения ([docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage)).
Например:

```
let server = client.guilds.get('id');
let channel = server.channels.get('id');
let message = await channel.fetchMessage('id');
await message.edit('text');
```

PS. Вы не можете редактировать сообщения других пользователей.

Comment: Выдает ошибку 
let message = await channel.fetchMessage('651381813721301002');
   ^^^^^

Comment: @CyphereKing, какую?